# VBA Excel - Sort a daily delivery manifest into groups based on complex rules

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a way to sort my Excel-Table. I wrote a very basic VBA to do this when it was a random sort only. Now there's complex parameters/rules I have to meet and it's way outside my skillset.

The problem: I receive a daily file with a list of items via shipments like the example below. The list can have as few as 1 and as many as 24 items. I have to sort these by restaurant.

```
Example Original List

ITEM    SHIPMENT

Oranges 1
Apples  1
Grapes  1
Pears   2
Pork    3
Chicken 4
Rice    5
Peas    5
Beans   5
Water   5
Corn    5
Milk    5
Eggs    5
Salmon  6
Tofu    7
Juice   8
Cheese  8
Salt    8
Pepper  9
Onions  10
Oats    11
Barley  11
Kale    11
Chips   12
```

The items need to be sorted out to 6 restaurants and there are complex rules:

Overall Rules

- No Restaurant can have more than 1 item from a shipment
- No Restaurant can have more than 4 items

Sorting Rules

1. Restaurant 1 always gets the first two items (Items 1-2)
2. Restaurant 2-5 evenly gets the next 16 items (Items 3-18)
3. Restaurant 6 gets the next 2 items (Items 19-20)
4. Restaurant 1 and 6 then evenly get the last 4 items (Items 21-24)
5. If there are more than 6 items in a shipment (more items than restaurants) the extra items stay in the warehouse.
6. The Overall Rules override the sorting rules. For example in our example list Restaurant 1 cannot have both Oranges and Apples since they are from the same shipment so the sort changes.

```
Example Sort

Restaurant 1    Shipment
Oranges         1
Pears           2
Rice            5
Kale            11

Restaurant 2    
Apples          1
Peas            5
Salmon          6
Salt            8

Restaurant 3    
Grapes          1
Beans           5
Tofu            7
Pepper          9

Restaurant 4
Pork            3
Water           5
Juice           8
Onions          10

Restaurant 5
Chicken         4
Corn            5
Cheese          8
Oats            11

Restaurant 6
Milk            5
Barley          11
Chips           12

Warehouse Items
Eggs            5
```

Looking at it as a whole now I'm not even sure this is possible and I have no idea how to go about doing it. If anyone has any input I'd love to hear it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is surely possible, as long the set of rules are "clear", should be able to build some logic around it. Looking at restaurant 1, has items 5 & 11... these are not coming in from the `Sorting Rules` as far as i can tell, so does that mean that after you apply sorting rules, you are giving away the left overs else based on `Overall Rules` to all restaurants evenly?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The numbers next to each item in the "example Sort" are which shipment they are from, not the item number. So those aren't items 5 & 11 but rather  7 & 23. However, you're right that item number 7, "rice", wouldn't go to restaurant 1 under the sorting rules. However, after giving out the rest of shipment 5 under the sorting rules, the remainder went to restaurant 1 and 6 out of order.

Comment: I have to second @DarXyde. If it is black and white, like you indicate in the question, then it is surely possible and in several different ways.  A pad of paper, a pencil, and about 30 minutes working out the logic for the two rules and first few conditions should be enough to jump start the coding process and you can add pieces as you go.  That is, unless you want a beautiful and concise algorithm, in which case I think you needed to crack open that math book about two years ago.  :)